How does the water get into this drainage pipe under the basement floor?
I've been watching videos about different types of basement drainage systems.  In this video, the guy describes how (in his opinion - I'm no expert) groundwater will bypass a traditional French drain.  Their system, which is installed much lower under the floor, is superior.  In this still picture their diagram shows a large plastic pipe (about 8" in diameter) being installed on a bed of small stones.

The video is quite convincing.  He describes the "cold joint" between the footing and the wall and how water will seep through it.  It is plain to see that the French drain sits above this level and would not control the water, but their system would.  In any case, my question is how does the water get into that black pipe?  It doesn't appear to be perforated at all.  I know one end terminates in a sump pump, but couldn't water only enter the pipe at its far end?  Confused!
Here is the video.  My screen grab is from 1:46.

usually a perforated pipe is used in this application, In a computer generated animation it really makes no difference which sort of pipe is used, because everything is fake.

Yes indeed but later on in the video the actual pipe is shown.  It is hard to determine whether it is perforated or not.

you should probably show the actual pipe in your question.

You likely meant to write the above comment for the question instead of your answer.

The black pipe is a standard 4" perforated drain pipe that you can get at any DIY box store or plumbing wholesaler.
At 3:24, you can better see the perforations at the bottom of the pipe:


The pipe is perforated, but it is installed with the perforations on the bottom, not top. The actual openings may be either small holes or slits which are difficult to see in the video. An image search using your favorite search engine for perforated drain pipe will give you some idea of the range of products offered.
